# Scala - pattern head/tail on Map

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a tail recursive method but i'm using Map and i don't know how to use Pattern Matching to check if Map is empty/null and get head/tail:

```
def aa(a:Map[String, Seq[Operation]]): Map[String, (Seq[Operation], Double)] = {

    def aaRec(xx:Map[String, Seq[Operation]],
              res:Map[String, (Seq[Operation], Double)],
              acc:Double = 0): Map[String, (Seq[Operation], Double)] = xx match {
      case ? => 
        res
      case _ => 
        val head = xx.head
        val balance = head._2.foldLeft(acc)(_ + _.amount)
        aaRec(xx.tail, res + (head._1 -> (head._2, balance)), balance)
    }

    aaRec(a, Map[String, (Seq[Operation], Double)]())

    }
}
```

What is the correct syntax on case empty map and case h :: t?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to pattern match on a map, but this code could be rewritten using basic combinator methods:

```scala
def aa(a:Map[String, Seq[Operation]]): Map[String, (Seq[Operation], Double)] =
  a.mapValues(seq => (seq, seq.map(_.amount).sum))
```

Comment: The usual warning: `mapValues` returns a view, so if you access the same key more than once, `seq.map(_.amount).sum` will be calculated each time.

Answer (score 5):

`Map` has no order so it has no `head` or `tail`.  It also has no `unapply/unapplySeq` method so you can't do pattern matching on a `Map`.

I think going with a `foldLeft` might be your best option.